# Feedforward disturbance signal compensation

Tags: matlab, software-implementation, control-systems, simulink

The reference [Feedforward control concepts through Interactive Tools](http://aer.ual.es/ilm/doc/Guzman_et_al_IFAC_WC_2011.pdf) says, to minimise the effect of the disturbance $d$ on the process output $y$, a compensator $G_{\text{ff}}=P_3/P_1$ shall be used. From a theory point of view, no problem. Even a few simple examples behave as expected.

[image: Block diagram illustrating the feedforward control]

Encouraged by that, I decided to implement three-phase inverter control in $dq$ reference frame. Inverter model is represented by LC filter equations:
$$
\text{L} \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}
i_\text{d} \\
i_\text{q} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_\text{dn} \\
v_\text{qn} \\
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{\text{d load}} \\
v_{\text{q load}} \\
\end{bmatrix} + \text{L} \omega
\begin{bmatrix}
i_\text{q} \\
-i_\text{d} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\text{C} \frac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}t}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_\text{d load} \\
v_\text{q load} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
i_\text{d} \\
i_\text{q} \\
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{\text{d load}} \\
i_{\text{q load}} \\
\end{bmatrix} + \text{C} \omega
\begin{bmatrix}
v_\text{q load} \\
-v_\text{d load} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
From there, I derive plant model and control structure in $dq$ reference frame (only $d$ frame is shown):
[image: three-phase inverter control strucure and plant model for d reference frame]

In this case disturbance  $i_{\text{d load}}$ is fed directly to the plant model. i.e. $P_3=1$. Open-loop inner loop equation is:
$$
G_\text{co}(s) = \underbrace{K_\text{P} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{s T_\text{I}} \right)} _\text{PI controller} \underbrace{ \left(\frac{1}{s \text{L}}\right) } _{\text{Process}}
$$
and closed loop ($P_1$) is
$$
G_\text{cc}(s) = \frac{G_\text{co}(s)}{1 + G_\text{co}(s)} = ... = \frac{s T_\text{I}+1}{s^2 \text{L} T_\text{I}/K_\text{P} + s T_\text{I} + 1}
$$
Compensator transfer fucntion is $G_{\text{ff}}=1/G_\text{cc}(s)$ and numerator is a higher order than the denominator.

- I cannot implement this transfer function in MATLAB Simulink. Is there a way forward?
- I don't see any issues with the method! Is this the right approach? Articles deal little with feed-forward signal or cross-coupling compensation.
- When I make $P_3$ equal to $P_1$, i.e. $G_{\text{ff}}=1$, the disturbance is eliminated. In other cases, there is a huge overshoot for step disturbance. It eventually stabilises.
- I also have to compensate the cross-coupling element $\omega\text{C}v_{\text{q load}}$ using the same compensator?
- In the real system (e.g. DSP), I will implement only the control part in $dq$ frame. Do I need to add compensators to load current and cross-coupling signals? Also, the plant's transfer function will be different and unknown. How to determine compensator there or leave it at 1 and only tune PI controller to get the desired response.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot implement this transfer function in MATLAB Simulink. Is there a way forward?

That's because you can't implement it *at all*.
$$
\frac{1}{G_\text{cc}(s)} = \frac{s^2 \text{L} T_\text{I}/K_\text{P} + s T_\text{I} + 1}{s T_\text{I}+1}, \tag 1
$$
which is impossible because it's not proper.  But consider two things: first, $P_3(s)$ may save you, and second, if it doesn't, there's an approximation that will.

If $P_3(s)$ is inherently low-pass, then your $G_{ff} = \frac{P_3(s)}{G_\text{cc}(s)}$ will become proper, or at least will have the same order in the numerator and the denominator.  Then it can be realized without pain.

If $P_3(s)$ *isn't* low-pass then you can approximate $G_{ff}$.  Consider $P_3(s) = 1$.  With a bit of rearrangement, you can get:
$$
\frac{1}{G_\text{cc}(s)} = k_1 s + k_0 + \frac{k_{lp}}{s T_I + 1}
$$
The low-pass filter is realizable, the proportional gain is realizable, and only the naked differentiator is unrealizable.  So let
$$
G_{ff}(s) = \frac{k_1 s}{\tau s + 1} + k_0 + \frac{k_{lp}}{s T_I + 1} \simeq \frac{1}{G_\text{cc}(s)}
$$

The smaller the $\tau$, the more this approaches the "ideal", but the more sensitive the system becomes to noise, and the bigger the signal is coming out of it.  The larger the $\tau$, the easier the system design gets, but the more error you have.

Choosing the right value for $\tau$ involves the cost of control, the anticipated power spectrum of the disturbance, the robustness of the system, what you really need to achieve, and a whole bunch of other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

1 - What transfer function are you trying to implement? The controller transfer function or the "plant" transfer function?

2 - You are trying to simulate some kind of inverter/active rectifier, right? Inverters are non-linear, you can simulate them with only linear blocks if you want but you will not be able to test your controller with the non-linearities that are present in real-life.

3 - What are P1 and P3 ?

4 - You kind of compensate your cross-coupling terms in the second image the $\omega Li_q$  and  $\omega Li_q$ terms. The cross-coupling terms are compensated to improve the response of your controller, but they are not technically needed.

5 - In a real-life implementation you don't have to compensate the cross-coupling terms but compensating the cross-coupling makes your control system settle faster if I recall correctly.